# Line 70, Column 191: Duplicate ID recipeslide. Is there a workaround?

Tags: php, html

I'm getting three multiple errors when trying to validate my code.

```
echo '<section id="featured">';
    $recipes = mysql_query("
        SELECT `id`,`name`, `image`, `description`
        FROM `recipe` 
        ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 4;
    ");

    while ($recipe = mysql_fetch_assoc($recipes)) {
    echo '<section id="recipeslide">';
    $recipe_id = $recipe['id'];


    echo "<a href='php/recipe.php?id=$recipe_id'><img src=\"{$recipe['image']}\" height=100 width=100 /></a><br />";

    echo '</section>';
    }


    echo '</section>';
```

This is the only place that I use the id of recipeslide but I think the validator is getting confused somehow and was wondering how I can fix this or do I ignore it?

It points out two other Id's that supposedly are duplicated.

It is also complaining about alt tags but I don't see that they would be effective in this situation.

[image]

Comment: `mysql` functions are [deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php). Please consider using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [Mysqli](http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).

Comment: You should use `class` instead of `id`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IDs must be unique.  You are using the same ID in a loop.  You could do something like:

```
$count = 1;
while ($recipe = mysql_fetch_assoc($recipes)) {
    echo '<section id="recipeslide' . $count++ . '">';
```

As for the alt attribute for `<img>`, [it's pretty much required](http://www.w3.org/community/webed/wiki/HTML/Elements/img#Requirements_for_providing_text_to_act_as_an_alternative_for_images) even if it's empty.

Comment: This fixed the validation but broke the look of the page :P I will have to fiddle around but thank you for that great piece of code.

Comment: @LawrenceSmith breaks the page how?  If there are styles for `#recipeslide` you should use a class instead/as well

Comment: probably just need to assign a class to that `section` tag and set that class's styles to whatever styles you had set for `#recipeslide`

Comment: I am guessing that the page was being styled by css based on that particular ID which no longer matches as the id has been changed

Comment: Well it's meant to display 4 items in a horizontal view but when adding that code they revert back to a vertical view.

Comment: so do what two people have recommended. it should fix your problem.

Comment: I don't understand @Anigel, the id is still the same.

Comment: no it's not. you added a count to the id in the code (remember this is in a `while` loop), so now there's a bunch of elements with ids like `recipeslide1`, `recipeslide2`, `recipeslide3`, etc. there's no longer an element with id `recipeslide`.

Comment: If you have used this solution then your id will not be the same, it will have a number on the end for each time through the loop. so first id is `recipeslide1` the second is `recipeslide2` etc

Answer (score 0):

You are giving an id in a loop

So you get an extra ID each time round the loop

if you have 3 recipes then the while loop runs 3 times with each insertion adding another

```
<section id="recipeslide">
```

The answer is to not set a static id on an element inside of a loop, you need to either use a unique id for each run through the loop or if it is just for styling, set a class rather than an id

Comment: So should I just ignore the validation issues?

Comment: no ... you should just not assign an id in a loop. that said, validation doesn't actually mean anything. i wouldn't worry about it too much unless you have a specific reason for needing to pass validation.

Comment: No you shouldn't ignore the validation issues.  You should fix them.  Either use class instead of id or add some kind of counter to the ID so that they are unique.